# XSLT v1.0 - how to create a variable with children [ IBM WATSON XML]

Tags: xml, xslt, watson

Best,

At this moment, we are using IBM Watson Explorer and there is an issue with the share-point connector. The connector seems to make the "wrong" conversion from original to WATSON URL, and this is what we are trying to fix through XSLT 1.0.

```
      <xsl:variable name="url-tokens" select="str:tokenize($seed-urls, '&#10;')" />
      <xsl:variable name="fixed-urls">

        <!-- &#10; == newline -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$url-tokens">
          <xsl:variable name="url-parts" select="viv:url-decompose(.)" />
          <!-- Append a slash ("/") to the path, unless the path already has a slash, or ends in ".aspx" -->
          <xsl:variable name="fixed-path" select="concat($url-parts/path,viv:if-else(viv:match($url-parts/path, '(\.aspx|\/)$'),'','/'))" />

          <!-- Rebuild the URL, but use the io-sp protocol and the fixed path (constructed above) -->

          <xsl:value-of select="viv:url-build($crawl-protocol, '', '', $url-parts/host, $url-parts/port, $fixed-path, '')" />
          <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
```

viv:url-decompose transforms the basic url into the following parts ("url-parts"): url-parts/host, url-parts/port and url-parts/path.

The Watson URL is based on a concatenation of url-parts/host and url-parts/path. We believe however that this decomposition isn't working as we expect. So because we can't delete any code, we have been trying to create a variant with the correct naming.

To give an example:
url-parts : www.sharepoint-domain.com/IT/PM/page_name
will be transformed via viv:url-decompose into :

- url-parts/host : www.sharepoint-domain.com
- url-parts/path : IT/PM/page_name
- url-parts/port :

which isn't correct for our setup:

What we need, is :

- url-parts/host : www.sharepoint-domain.com/IT/PM/
- url-parts/path : page_name
- url-parts/port :

One option that might work, is:

- name the original **url-parts** into e.g. **url-parts-temp**
- create our own **url-parts** from **url-parts-temp** by using the concat and taking the substring of */IT/PM/*

**Question**

How do you create a variable with children in such a way that this new variable acts as if nothing changed? (e.g. ** $url-parts/host** and ** $url-parts/path** must still work as originally intended)

**Thus**

```
<xsl:variable name="url-parts-temp" select="viv:url-decompose(.)" />
<!-- Magic
<xsl:variable name="url-parts/host" select="concat($url-parts/host,'/IT/PM/'" />
<xsl:variable name="url-parts/path" select="substring($url-parts/path,6)" />
<xsl:variable name="url-parts/port" select="$url-parts-temp/port" />
-->
<xsl:variable name="fixed-path" select="concat($url-parts/path, ... )" />
```

kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, name the first decompose differently:

```
<xsl:variable name="url-parts-temp" select="viv:url-decompose(.)" />
```

Secondly, create a variable *url* together with it belonging values:

```
<xsl:variable name="url">
    <path><xsl:value-of select="substring($url-parts-temp/path,string-length('it/pm')+2)"/></path>
    <host><xsl:value-of select="concat($url-parts-temp/host,$url-parts-temp/path)"/></host>
    <port>$url-parts-temp/port</port>
    <query>$url-parts-temp/query</query>
</xsl:variable>
```

Thirdly, use **exsl:node-set** regarding to the variable *$url*:

```
<xsl:variable name="url-parts" select="exsl:node-set($url)" />
```

**Result** now you can use url-parts, just like before:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$url-parts/host" />
<xsl:value-of select="$url-parts/path" />
```